# Forbid auto orientation to Landscape, can manually set one controller to landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, orientation

I forbid whole app orientation to landscape. But I want to allow only one view controller --- MPMoviePlayerController auto rotate, I knew I can rotate view manually, but the status bar still in portrait.

I've set info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

I don't want the entire app can auto orientation.

So my problem is:

1. Whether I can just allow this view auto orientation landscape (I've already forbidden app orientation to landscape).
2. If 1 is NO, then, is there anyway to set status bar to landscape mode?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set status bar in landscape mode like below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO]
```

And for your status bar to rotate. Try like below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Also test it on device.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal I tried, but none of them work. Is it because I set the info.plist only for portrait? you can see my question update.